# How to find all forms of a word ?

Tags: meaning, grammar

How to find all forms of a word ?

Given that you have a noun , a verb, an adjective or an adverb ?

The forms i am referring to are :

Noun
Verb
Adjective
Adverb

Thanks !

Comment: https://github.com/gutfeeling/word_forms

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries usually list all important POS forms.

Also, words are routinely verbified, nounified, and all sorts of interuse is widespread today.

That nearly covers everything, I guess.

Comment: Some 'interuse' being better established than other!

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable grammar should have tables of the forms of noun, adjective and a table of the verb conjugation. But I admit that form tables are not favoured by English grammars. And the conjugation tables are mostly horrible, mixed with continuous forms, so that it is really difficult to understand the conjugation system. Adverbs are invariable, they have only one form.